# How do I get this box to move left after having it move to the right and down?

Tags: java, processing

I have to make a box move zig-zag all the way to the bottom of the screen. I figured out how to have the box start at the top left corner, move to the top right corner, then it moves down (one complete box of (x,y,90,90)). I'm stuck now because I realize that the next if-statement I want to write is fighting with the first if-statement to glide the box to the left end of the screen. I've tried while and for loops to overcome the problem but I honestly don't know what to do or where to do. I need the program to do this all the way down the screen and stop at rest(810,810,90,90) and stop. Any suggestions?

Here's my main code:

```
WBox v1; 
int a = 0;
float x=0;
float y=0;
void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  frameRate(1000);
  v1 = new WBox();
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  rect(x,y,90,90);

  if(x<810){
    x+=1;
  } else if(y < 90){
    y+=1;
  } else if (x<=0){
    x-=1;
  }
}
```

Here's the class:
    **class WBox{ 
      PVector wb;

```
 void box(int tempX, int tempY) {

   wb = new PVector(tempX, tempY); 
   wb.mult(a);//
   rect(wb.x, wb.y, 90, 90); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Full disclaimer: it would be better practice to use the WBox class differently to achieve this, but as you seem to be a beginner, I'm going to stick to easy stuff. You can ask me questions if you feel like it, I'll hang around for a while.

---

Instead of having a hardcoded number for movement speed, let's try it with a variable:

`float boxSpeedX = 1;`

The we just have to figure out an algorithm to get it to go down. The best way to do this is to use pseudocode.

[image: /ˈso͞odōˌkōd/]

In other words: write the logic behind the machine code. Something like this:

1. Rectangle must move horizontally until it reaches a border
2. When it reaches a border, it must go down 90 pixels
3. Then it moves horizontally toward the other side
4. When it reaches (810, 810) it should stop and rest.

Seems easy enough. Let's go closer to the code:

```
if (reached a border)
  box move horizontally toward the other border
else
  box move downward 90 pixels

if (box reached (810, 810)
  stop
```

Closer!

```
// let's start with the stop condition
if (box reached 810, 810)
  do nothing
else
  if (box is on an horizontal line)
    x += speed
    if (box reached right side)
      speed = -1 // so next time it'll go left
      y +=1 // this way the box isn't on an horizontal line anymore
    else if (box reached left side)
      speed = 1
      y += 1 
  else
    y += 1
```

Now let's elaborate on some of the details:

```
(box is on an horizontal line):
  horizontal lines are multiples of 90 pixels

(box reached right side)
  x == 810

(box reached left side)
  x == 0
```

We'll use the [modulo operator](https://www.ipracticemath.com/learn/numbersense/modulo-operator) to know if the y number is a multiple or 90. Take some time to understand this operator, it's really, really useful. In short, it will give you the remains of an integer division (for example, if you do 13/5, instead of having a number with decimals the integer division will say "2" and the modulo will say "3" because there's 2 times 5 in 13, not more "full 5", and there's 3 units left after this operation).

I feel like we're close enough, now. The rest is just translating this in code. I did it for you, and I've left comments in the code. You can copy and paste it into a Processing IDE and it'll run. You can build on this example to get your box to do whatever you want.

```
WBox v1; 
int a = 0;
float x=0;
float y=0;
float boxSpeedX = 1;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  frameRate(1000);
  v1 = new WBox();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  rect(x, y, 90, 90);

  moveBox();
}

void moveBox() {
  // first check for the stop condition:
  if (x != 810 || y != 810) {  // the box will move only while the stop condition isn't met
    // if the box is on a horizontal line, let's move it
    if (y % 90 == 0) { // the '%' operator's name is 'modulo', it's awesome and useful
      x += boxSpeedX;
      // once the box has moved, let's check if we need to steer it down:
      if (x == 0) { // if the box reaches the left side
        boxSpeedX = 1; //next time the box moves horizontally, it'll go right
        y += 1; // let's move down
      } else if (x == 810) {
        boxSpeedX = -1;
        y += 1;
      }
    } else {  // if the box isn't on an horizontal line, let's move it downward until it reaches a new line
      y += 1;
    }
  }
}

class WBox { 
  PVector wb;

  void box(int tempX, int tempY) {

    wb = new PVector(tempX, tempY); 
    wb.mult(a);//
    rect(wb.x, wb.y, 90, 90);
  }
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a beginner lol, I'm way better with python so I'm struggling to try to convert from python to processing in my head. I kept trying (x!=0 || y<90), but this makes so much more sense and it's waaay cleaner than having to constantly do change the y for every time the box goes down the line. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't speak about it, but the way this is coded, you have no need for the WBox class at all. Your rectangle is hardcoded and it's position are global variables. If you plan on making this into something more elaborate, I strongly suggest that you make it a real class and use it as one.

Comment: I noticed that when I deleted the class, it still worked. I initially was doing this as a boolean with true and false, but I got completely confused so I wanted to do it in a simpler way more related to python. I'm going to go back and use this as a guide to implement it into the boolean program with the class.

Comment: Great! OOP is a nice paradigm, you'll see. Hope to hear about it again, good luck.